# How to push elements to a Excel range in order to stringify an object/array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I construct the following string in an Excel formula:

> {"ios": [1601291711],"android": [1601291129],"amazon": [1601221648]}

The different platforms are independent elements, so I can have 1 to 3 active platforms. In a simple 2x3 excel table, active platforms are enabled when an "x" is placed and disabled when the "x" is deleted.

Using Named Ranges, iosV = '"ios": [1601291711]', androidV = '"android": [1601291129]',... On the other hand, activePlatforms is the range 1x3 with all the "x".

I wrote a formula which works fine:

```
="{" & CHOOSE(COUNTA(activePlatforms),
IFS(ios="x",iosV,android="x",androidV,amazon="x",amazonV),
IFS(
    AND(ios="x",android="x"), JOIN(", ",iosV,android),
    AND(ios="x", amazon="x"), JOIN(", ", iosV, amazonV),
    AND(android="x",amazon="x"),JOIN(", ",androidV,amazonV)
),
JOIN(", ",iosV,androidV,amazonV)) & "}"
```

I'm looking for a shorter formula and/or alternative ways to do it. I'm not interested in custom formulas (aka Google Script / VBA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for n-platforms :)

First, build next table:
[Active Platforms Table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsgWL.png)
At cell "E1" formula is:

```
=SORT(D1:D4,1,FALSE)
```

Then, paste next formula where you need the string construction:

```
="{"&JOIN(",",OFFSET(E1,0,0,4-COUNTBLANK(E1:E4),1))&"}"
```

That'll do!